# Caching all jsp pages content except one jsp page in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, caching, struts2

Is there any way to avoid caching only for one page? I have to cache all page content & leave only one page which will not store the content.

I tried the caching control from the *interceptor* which will check the module name & avoid caching for that module.
But this did not help me out because if I set the header with no-cache for only one module page, it also affects other module page with no-cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do that (Add these lines on top of the page)

**Inside JSPs**

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

**Via HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```